# Extract specific objects based on the specific key in it

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, typescript

I have a huge JSON file and I need to keep only specified results.

I'm trying to filter but I get an error....

Here is a short sample json :

```js
var data = [{"annonces":{"20165794":{"id":"20165794","type":"vente","bien":"appartement","ville":"Aix-en-Provence","titre":"T2 de 38m2 \u00e0 Aix en Provence","texte":"bonjour, je met en location mon T2 de 38m2 en r\u00e9z de chauss\u00e9e de ma villa \u00e0 Aix en Provence. Coin terrasse de 12m2, grand salon avec cuisine ouverte, salle de bain, coin bureau et chambre. Chauffage au sol, machine \u00e0 laver, lit canap\u00e9, table, chaise, cuisini\u00e8re et frigidaire. L?appartement est lou\u00e9 en semi-meubl\u00e9 afin de permettre au locataire de ramener sa touche personnelle. Eau, chauffage, gaz et \u00e9lectricit\u00e9 inclus dans le loyer.","cp":"13100","date":"2021-03-02","prix":"720","prix_evolution":[],"loyer_cc":"1","meuble":"1","pieces":"2","chambres":"0","surface":"38","sources":[{"source":"leboncoin.fr","url":"https:\/\/www.leboncoin.fr\/locations\/1937502222.htm"}],"img":"https:\/\/image1.marketing-immo.fr\/bG9jYXRpb24vMjAyMS8wMy8wMi8xNjE0NjgzMjY3Njk0OTA4NjIuanBn","tel_1":"0683535836","tel_2":"","stop":false,"stop_date":"","annonceur":[],"email":"","latitude":"","longitude":"","adresse":"","bloctel":""},"20165771":{"id":"20165771","type":"location","bien":"appartement","ville":"Aix-en-Provence","titre":"T2 meubl\u00e9 30m2 Aix-en-Provence 740eur","texte":"Appartement deux pi\u00e8ces dans le centre ville d'Aix, disponible d\u00e8s le 1er Avril. Situ\u00e9 place des Pr\u00eacheurs, cet appartement est plein de charme et tr\u00e8s lumineux . Aucun vis \u00e0 vis car situ\u00e9 au dernier \u00e9tage; il donne sur les toits avec vue sur l'\u00e9glise de la Madeleine. Partiellement meubl\u00e9 (car la locataire actuelle y a rajouter certains de ses meubles), il y a un lit deux places et une armoire dans la chambre. Un frigo, une machine \u00e0 laver, deux plaques \u00e9lectriques et un meuble de rangement dans le coin salon\/cuisine. Salle de bain avec baignoire et petite fen\u00eatre, s\u00e9par\u00e9e des toilettes. Il est \u00e0 une minute \u00e0 pieds du haut du cours Mirabeau et 10mn \u00e0 pieds de la rotonde et de ses arr\u00eats de bus.","cp":"13100","date":"2021-03-02","prix":"740","prix_evolution":[],"loyer_cc":"1","meuble":"1","pieces":"2","chambres":"0","surface":"30","sources":[{"source":"leboncoin.fr","url":"https:\/\/www.leboncoin.fr\/locations\/1937545795.htm"}],"img":"https:\/\/image1.marketing-immo.fr\/bG9jYXRpb24vMjAyMS8wMy8wMi8xNjE0NjgzMDc4NDcyMDQ1Ni5qcGc-","tel_1":"0610857596","tel_2":"","stop":false,"stop_date":"","annonceur":[],"email":"","latitude":"","longitude":"","adresse":"","bloctel":""},"20165761":{"id":"20165761","type":"location","bien":"appartement","ville":"Aix-en-Provence","titre":"Beau T2\/3 aix centre au calme","texte":"A louer appartement meubl\u00e9 ou non T2\/3 aix hypercentre au calme dans cour int\u00e9rieure sans vis \u00e0 vis Compos\u00e9 d?une cuisine avec grand \u00eelot central (lave vaisselle, lave linge, four, plaques vitro, r\u00e9frig\u00e9rateur) En mezzanine , un espace d\u00e9tente ou bureau (hauteur 1,5m) Un salon Une chambre en mezzanine avec Velux Une salle d?eau avec Wc et douche Appartement enti\u00e8rement refait en 2019 Id\u00e9al jeune(s) actif(s) Libre \u00e0 partir du 1er avril Garanties demand\u00e9es Garanties","cp":"13100","date":"2021-03-02","prix":"1100","prix_evolution":[],"loyer_cc":"1","meuble":"1","pieces":"2","chambres":"0","surface":"45","sources":[{"source":"leboncoin.fr","url":"https:\/\/www.leboncoin.fr\/locations\/1937348263.htm"}],"img":"https:\/\/image1.marketing-immo.fr\/bG9jYXRpb24vMjAyMS8wMy8wMi81ODcyMzY2MS5qcGc-","tel_1":"","tel_2":"","stop":true,"stop_date":"2013-11-04 10:14:06","annonceur":[],"email":"","latitude":"","longitude":"","adresse":"","bloctel":""}}}]
```

Here is my function to keep only elements where 'type' is 'vente'

```js
var data_filter = data.filter( element => element.type =="vente")
console.log(data_filter)
```

I get this error :

> Property 'type' does not exist on type '{ "20165794": { id: string;
> type: string; bien: string; ville: string; titre: string; texte:
> string; cp: string; date: string; prix: string; prix_evolution: any[];
> loyer_cc: string; meuble: string; pieces: string; ... 13 more ...;
> bloctel: string; }; }'.ts(2339)

Any idea how to get it to works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data[0].annonces is an object, so you can use forin loop, e.g:

```
const data = [{"annonces":{"20165794":{"id":"20165794","type":"vente","bien":"appartement","ville":"Aix-en-Provence","titre":"T2 de 38m2 \u00e0 Aix en Provence","texte":"bonjour, je met en location mon T2 de 38m2 en r\u00e9z de chauss\u00e9e de ma villa \u00e0 Aix en Provence. Coin terrasse de 12m2, grand salon avec cuisine ouverte, salle de bain, coin bureau et chambre. Chauffage au sol, machine \u00e0 laver, lit canap\u00e9, table, chaise, cuisini\u00e8re et frigidaire. L?appartement est lou\u00e9 en semi-meubl\u00e9 afin de permettre au locataire de ramener sa touche personnelle. Eau, chauffage, gaz et \u00e9lectricit\u00e9 inclus dans le loyer.","cp":"13100","date":"2021-03-02","prix":"720","prix_evolution":[],"loyer_cc":"1","meuble":"1","pieces":"2","chambres":"0","surface":"38","sources":[{"source":"leboncoin.fr","url":"https:\/\/www.leboncoin.fr\/locations\/1937502222.htm"}],"img":"https:\/\/image1.marketing-immo.fr\/bG9jYXRpb24vMjAyMS8wMy8wMi8xNjE0NjgzMjY3Njk0OTA4NjIuanBn","tel_1":"0683535836","tel_2":"","stop":false,"stop_date":"","annonceur":[],"email":"","latitude":"","longitude":"","adresse":"","bloctel":""},"20165771":{"id":"20165771","type":"location","bien":"appartement","ville":"Aix-en-Provence","titre":"T2 meubl\u00e9 30m2 Aix-en-Provence 740eur","texte":"Appartement deux pi\u00e8ces dans le centre ville d'Aix, disponible d\u00e8s le 1er Avril. Situ\u00e9 place des Pr\u00eacheurs, cet appartement est plein de charme et tr\u00e8s lumineux . Aucun vis \u00e0 vis car situ\u00e9 au dernier \u00e9tage; il donne sur les toits avec vue sur l'\u00e9glise de la Madeleine. Partiellement meubl\u00e9 (car la locataire actuelle y a rajouter certains de ses meubles), il y a un lit deux places et une armoire dans la chambre. Un frigo, une machine \u00e0 laver, deux plaques \u00e9lectriques et un meuble de rangement dans le coin salon\/cuisine. Salle de bain avec baignoire et petite fen\u00eatre, s\u00e9par\u00e9e des toilettes. Il est \u00e0 une minute \u00e0 pieds du haut du cours Mirabeau et 10mn \u00e0 pieds de la rotonde et de ses arr\u00eats de bus.","cp":"13100","date":"2021-03-02","prix":"740","prix_evolution":[],"loyer_cc":"1","meuble":"1","pieces":"2","chambres":"0","surface":"30","sources":[{"source":"leboncoin.fr","url":"https:\/\/www.leboncoin.fr\/locations\/1937545795.htm"}],"img":"https:\/\/image1.marketing-immo.fr\/bG9jYXRpb24vMjAyMS8wMy8wMi8xNjE0NjgzMDc4NDcyMDQ1Ni5qcGc-","tel_1":"0610857596","tel_2":"","stop":false,"stop_date":"","annonceur":[],"email":"","latitude":"","longitude":"","adresse":"","bloctel":""},"20165761":{"id":"20165761","type":"location","bien":"appartement","ville":"Aix-en-Provence","titre":"Beau T2\/3 aix centre au calme","texte":"A louer appartement meubl\u00e9 ou non T2\/3 aix hypercentre au calme dans cour int\u00e9rieure sans vis \u00e0 vis Compos\u00e9 d?une cuisine avec grand \u00eelot central (lave vaisselle, lave linge, four, plaques vitro, r\u00e9frig\u00e9rateur) En mezzanine , un espace d\u00e9tente ou bureau (hauteur 1,5m) Un salon Une chambre en mezzanine avec Velux Une salle d?eau avec Wc et douche Appartement enti\u00e8rement refait en 2019 Id\u00e9al jeune(s) actif(s) Libre \u00e0 partir du 1er avril Garanties demand\u00e9es Garanties","cp":"13100","date":"2021-03-02","prix":"1100","prix_evolution":[],"loyer_cc":"1","meuble":"1","pieces":"2","chambres":"0","surface":"45","sources":[{"source":"leboncoin.fr","url":"https:\/\/www.leboncoin.fr\/locations\/1937348263.htm"}],"img":"https:\/\/image1.marketing-immo.fr\/bG9jYXRpb24vMjAyMS8wMy8wMi81ODcyMzY2MS5qcGc-","tel_1":"","tel_2":"","stop":true,"stop_date":"2013-11-04 10:14:06","annonceur":[],"email":"","latitude":"","longitude":"","adresse":"","bloctel":""}}}]

type getVenteFromObjTypes = {
  [key: string]: any;
};

function getVenteFromObj(obj: getVenteFromObjTypes) {
  const results = [];
  for (const elem in obj) {
    const tmp = obj[elem]?.type;
    if (tmp === "vente") results.push(obj[elem]);
  }

  return results;
}

console.log(getVenteFromObj(data[0].annonces));
```

Comment: Thanks PS-PARSA but I get this error :

Failed to compile.

src/app/modal-edit-full/modal-edit-full.page.ts:48:27 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

48     const tmp = obj[elem]?.type;
                             ~
src/app/modal-edit-full/modal-edit-full.page.ts:48:32 - error TS1005: ':' expected.

48     const tmp = obj[elem]?.type;

Comment: @RunfastWebmaster what's your typescript version?

Comment: "typescript": "~3.4.3"

Comment: PS-PARSA, I tried your code with Typescript online and your code is working. Thank you !!

Comment: @RunfastWebmaster hmmm, optional chaining added in version (3.7), you have two way, 1: update your typescript version (recommended) and 2: change `const tmp = obj[elem]?.type;` to `const tmp = obj[elem].hasOwnProperty("type") ? obj[elem].type : undefined;`.